# In Firebase console what does time values signify?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-performance

I am checking my app's traces in Firebase console, and I am just wondering what these time values signify? Because as you can see in first Image

[image]

Median is between `496ms-2.29s` but if we will look at trend over time then it shows 95th percentile as `4.00s`, now how can this value which is `4.00s` is not present in Distribution chart?

In the second image as you can see clearly the first chart value's 95th percentile shows value `2.37s` which is also greater than `2.29s`, shown in the distribution chart. Also why only 95th percentile, why they are not showing last value[maximum value] like for my case it is `4.00s`, then it would become really very helpful in analytics.

[image]

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the console's display of your data, please file a bug report: http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for telling, I will report the bug? Also, can you tell me according to the data which I am getting in my firebase console, is this normal behaviour? Or you too think that there is any bug? I really like Firebase and I am really dependent on it, that's why I want a quick fix, my app is going to come in production in just a few days.

Comment: I don't know if it's normal - that's why I'm suggesting that you report it as a bug.  The issue will be sent to engineering teams for them to decide if it's correct or not.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah, I have reported the bug, now waiting for a reply from their end, hope it gets resolved soon.